# Is this the correct way to find the value of $(-1)^{1/2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Is this the correct way to find the value of $(-1)^{1/2}$:
[image]

---

I used the Taylor series and then substituted $x=-2$ and $k=2$:

[image]

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to format your question using MathJax without images please. BTW, welcome to Math SE. Glad to have you here! Please follow guidelines for asking questions.

Comment: For fractional exponents, the Taylor series for $(1+x)^a$ is only valid for $|x|\le 1$.

Comment: But,why only for |x|<(or equal to)1?.Could you provide any proof for that?

Comment: Just a question, is $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ not the same as $\sqrt{-1}$? Which is defined as $i$

Comment: OP what do you mean by value? If you mean a real number then you're on a wild goose chase. There is no real number whose square is $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a general theorem in power series theory (look up "Cauchy-Hadamard theorem" and "radius of convergence")

> Let $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ be a power series. Then:
>
> - for all $z\in\Bbb C$ such that $\lvert z\rvert\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}<1$ the series converges;
> - for all $z\in\Bbb C$ such that $\lvert z\rvert\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}>1$ the series does not converge.

Now, the Taylor series at $c=0$ of $(1+z)^\alpha$ is indeed $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\prod_{h=0}^{k-1}(\alpha-h)}{k!}z^k$, which we usually shorten by setting $\binom\alpha k:=\frac1{k!}\prod_{h=0}^{k-1}(\alpha-h)$.

Fact is that for all $\alpha\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb N$, $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\binom\alpha n\right\rvert^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\ln\frac{\lvert \alpha-k\rvert}{k}\right)\stackrel{\text{Stolz-Cesàro}}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\frac{\lvert \alpha-n\rvert}n}=e^0=1$$

So, we can safely assert that, if you actually went on to evaluate the partial sums, you'd see a non-convergent sequence. In fact, the general terms of the series will become arbitrarily large in module themselves, as you may be starting to see by inspecting their pattern: it's $-\frac{(2n-3)!!}{n!}$ (where by "$!!$" I mean the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)). Since $\frac{(2n+1)!!}{n!}\ge 2^{n}$, we have the rough estimate $$\frac{(2n-3)!!}{n!}\ge \frac{2^{n-2}}{n(n-1)}\to\infty.$$